# Convert string which is read from a file to json object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a string from a file and want to convert it into a `json` object
File content: `{name:"sda"}`

Code:

```
var fs=require('fs');

var dir='./folder/';
fs.readdir(dir,function(err,files){
    if (err) throw err;

    files.forEach(function(file){


        fs.readFile(dir+file,'utf-8',function(err,jsonData){
            if (err) throw err;
            var content=jsonData;
            var data=JSON.stringify(content);
            console.log(data);
        });

    });
```

But I am getting this output: `{name:\"sda\"}`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** method which converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, you can also use **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** method which parses a string as JSON:

```
fs.readFile(dir+file,'utf-8',function(err, jsonData){
    if (err) throw err;    
    var content = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
    console.log(content);

    var data = JSON.parse(content);
    console.log(data);

});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var jsonData = '{name:"sda"}',
    content = JSON.stringify(jsonData),
    data = JSON.parse(content);

pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: cant do JSON.parse because it is not in json format When i am doing that i am getting this error:- Unexpected token name

Comment: In that case use a combination of the two methods, I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Since your file is not a valid JSON, you can use `eval` (it's a dirty hack but it works), example :

```js
data = '{name:"sda"}';
eval('foo = ' + data);
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: can't use eval can u give me any other way

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you use eval? It's the quickest way, the other way implies to parse your invalid "json" and build an object from it. Something like that: http://jsbin.com/xexohejuzu/edit?js,output